# Render OxyPlot graph in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, graphing, oxyplot

I would like to dock an OxyPlot graph in my windows form and graph the function `y = 2x - 7`. I have downloaded OxyPlot and added the references to my project. I use the following code to add the plot to my form:

```
public partial class GraphForm : Form
{
    public OxyPlot.WindowsForms.Plot Plot;

    public Graph()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Plot = new OxyPlot.WindowsForms.Plot();
        Plot.Model = new PlotModel();
        Plot.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(Plot);

        Plot.Model.PlotType = PlotType.XY;
        Plot.Model.Background = OxyColor.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
        Plot.Model.TextColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

With this code I see the white background, the control has been created, but it's only a white background. I've looked around the members of the `OxyPlot.Plot` class but I couldn't find a way to plat my equation. How can I plot my equation in the graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add some data to display, you add this to the Models Series property.

Line (X,Y) graph example.

```
    public Graph()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Plot = new OxyPlot.WindowsForms.Plot();
        Plot.Model = new PlotModel();
        Plot.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(Plot);

        Plot.Model.PlotType = PlotType.XY;
        Plot.Model.Background = OxyColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255);
        Plot.Model.TextColor = OxyColor.FromRGB(0, 0, 0);

        // Create Line series
        var s1 = new LineSeries { Title = "LineSeries", StrokeThickness = 1 };
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2,7));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(7, 9));
        s1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(9, 4));

        // add Series and Axis to plot model
        Plot.Model.Series.Add(s1);
        Plot.Model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom, 0.0, 10.0));
        Plot.Model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Left, 0.0, 10.0));

    }
```

This Example:

[image]

Comment: Updated with better example

Comment: I'm not trying to make a bar graph. I am trying to graph a line. I need to graph the function `y = 2x - 7`, which is an equation in slope-intercept form. The bar-graph does not help me, as I cannot simply add the data manually to the graph. Each point on the line would be data, and there is no possible way I could individually add the points. I want plot a line in the graph like you would in algebra in high-school.

Comment: Oh I see you've updated it. Let me see what I can do with your example.

Comment: Is there any way I could see the negative regions? So the graph is broken up into quadrants? Like the upper left is (-x, +y), the upper right is (+x, +y), the lower left is (-x,-y), and the lower right is (+x,-y), and the axis' would like like a cross-hair?

Comment: Yes, you will just have to setup the axis the way you want, I just set the Axis Min/Max, you could remove them, or add your own values, there is a bunch of example applications on the Oxplot site.http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/releases/view/76035

Comment: Now nothing is displaying, I don't even see a white background. I had to use `FromArgb(a,r,g,b)` instead of `FromRGB(r,g,b)` because out of nowhere it said that `FromRGB` is not a member of `OxyColor`.

Comment: Nevermind, I take that back! It works just fine, I accidentally left a bit of the of old code in when I pasted yours.

Comment: There's no way to set up the axes in the middle in kind of a cross-hair configuration. I looked in the `AxisPosition` class.

Comment: @Brandon Miller: You can have the axis appear that way by setting the `PositionAtZeroCrossing` property to `true`. See http://www.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser/, specifically "Zero crossing axis" in the "Axis examples" section.